# Try to do typecast but getting CAP#1 error

Tags: java

Playing around with type casting for a project I am about to start I found this error unexpectedly:

```
incompatible types: Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to myObj
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends ImyObj from capture of ? extends ImyObj
```

The code that caused this error:

```
ImyObj testObj = new myObj();
System.out.println(testObj.sayHi());
myObj testObj2 = (testObj.getClass()) testObj;
System.out.println(testObj2.sayBye());
```

However this works fine:

```
ImyObj testObj = new myObj();
System.out.println(testObj.sayHi());
myObj testObj2 = (myObj) testObj;
System.out.println(testObj2.sayBye());
```

Shouldn't they both do the same thing or am I missing something? I currently have Java 1.7_51 installed. It has been a while since I touched Java(before 1.7), as I got immersed in Python 2.7.

EDIT:

Louis Wasserman's answer also raises the same error.

Comment: `getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends ImyObj>` [Read the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass())

Comment: Unfortunately that does not explain the error.

Comment: How so? You're trying to use an instance of `Class` in a cast which isn't valid. Aside from that, the returned class is "Something that extends ImyObj" ... which makes it a bit hard to use for casting. (And why using `.cast()` from that returned instance doesn't work).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first problem is that you're trying to use an *instance* of `Class` as a *type* cast. That's not valid - it has to be a type.

That aside, if you try to do (I've renamed `myObj` to `MyObj` for clarity / proper naming):

```
ImyObj testObj = new MyObj();
MyObj testObj2 testObj.getClass().cast(testObj);
```

It won't work.

`testObj.getClass()` is going to return a `Class<? extends ImyObj>` which is "Something that extends ImyObject". It can't be used to cast to a specific subclass; that's what the error is saying.

If you used:

```
MyObj testObj2 = MyObj.class.cast(testObj);
```

It would work; you're using the specific class. The same would be true if you had:

```
MyObj mo = new MyObj();
MyObj testObj2 mo.getClass().cast(testObj);
```

In this case `mo.getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends MyObj>` which *can* be used to cast to a `MyObj` because the target is a `MyObj` rather than some subclass of `MyObj`

And if `testObj` *wasn't* an instance of `MyObj` it would throw a `java.lang.ClassCastException`